# HTML and JavaScript from another server?

Tags: google-apps-script

With Google Apps Script, we need to create the HTML and its JavaScript within the Apps Script project itself. I was wondering if there is a way where I can get the HTML from another server?

Basically, the idea is to reuse an existing HTML/JavaScript file which was developed for a non-appscript project and make relevant changes so as to support appsScript.

I don't want my HTML file to be part of the Google Apps Script and instead will be served from an external server. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

You could load the external files using client-side code or server-side code.

- To use client side code use `XMLHttpRequest()`, `jQuery`, `<script src="..." />`, etc.
- To use server side code use UrlFetchApp Service to get content from a URL.

Related

- [How to load external html into a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19370417/1595451)
- [How can I load external html files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43637730/1595451)
- [inject external javascript file in google app script(Google Docs)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26731438/1595451)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ruben. Going further, lets say I get my HTML/JS from another server. In the JS file, I might have to call a server-side function which populates a spread-sheet. Ideally, I will have to use google.script.run.functionName(). functionName would have to be in a .gs file in the apps-script project. Right? 

Can this function or the .gs file also reside in the remote server?

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is no code or minimal code to reside in my apps-script project and rest everything should be served from a remote server. 

Is this possible with apps-script?

Comment: @Ekalavya What about if you try that and share with us your findings?